# How to manage dependencies in c++

Tags: c++, maven, version-control, build, ivy

I have a big repository with a lot of separate modules (executable and so files) some dependent on another (and dependent on a third party libraries that are not in the repo).

I want to be able to pull only one module in this repository and be able to build it independently.

btw - I use scons as build tool in Linux and windows environment.

I saw in this site (and more) that there is two approach to this problem:

1. create in each module repository the directory "dependency" or any similar name and set all the repositories that this module depend on as sub repositories in this directory.

   *Problems:*

   1. it doesn't solve the problem of third-party which are not handle in my SCM.
   2. it makes the build procedure a lot more slow
   3. its ugly,  a lot of multiples in my base project dir.
2. create "binary repository" or "build artifact repository" and manage dependencies with it.

This looks like the best solution for me, but i dont understand how to do it practically.

I saw nuget for c# windows developers (and also little c++ but only in windows)  and ivy / maven for java developers but cant find any tool thats handle it for c++.

My question is -  how to create a dependency management with c++ code ?

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies in C++ are managed via header files and forward declarations.
Generally you should prefer forward declarations as much as possible and include header files when there's no way around it. This usually gives you the benefit that as long as you don't change the interface of a class the recompilation should only touch a single object file.

I suspect you also want something more complex, having to do with the way your build is set-up. That has very little to do with c++. If you want a better answer for this be more explicit regarding your build setup.

Answer (score 0):

The [maven nar (Native Archive) plugin](https://github.com/maven-nar/nar-maven-plugin) can help you with this. It's a plugin to maven that lets you build native archives on a platform. You can then use the standard maven dependency feature for c/c++ dependencies as well.

Comment: Is there any why to do it without maven ?   i'm currently working with scons as a build system.